# Dynamcially Creating a table inside a panel in C#.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is my code

```
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel panel1 = new Panel();
        Label newLabel = new Label();
        newLabel.ID = "lbltest";
        newLabel.Text = "my new label..";
        panel1.Controls.Add(newLabel);
    }
```

I cant see the my label text  when i click the button

Any help appreciate

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You must add your panel inside of any control which exists on your page.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the Panel to some control in your web page or your top level form element if you don't have anywhere else to put it.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel panel1 = new Panel();
    Label newLabel = new Label();
    newLabel.ID = "lbltest";
    newLabel.Text = "my new label..";
    panel1.Controls.Add(newLabel);
    this.Form.Controls.Add(panel1); // YOU ARE MISSING THIS
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `Panel` to the page:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel panel1 = new Panel();
    Label newLabel = new Label();
    newLabel.ID = "lbltest";
    newLabel.Text = "my new label..";
    panel1.Controls.Add(newLabel);

    //Do this
    SomeControlOnYourPage.Controls.Add(panel1);
}
```